# Can anyone help me fix my AC unit

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning, furnace

so we were having problems with a stripped wire that runs from the AC outside to the hvac inside so for a few days the ac did not work. We had someone come out and he ran a new wire but now the AC won't shut off unless we remove the thermostat from the wall. It's a vivint smart thermostat. Only 4 wires no c wire. When I look at the have wiring thought the guy did, he connected a C wire. Can anyone help? How am I supposed to fix that without spending more money.

Comment: disconnect the Y wire from thermostat and see if that works. If it does you need new thermostat

Comment: Turn the switch on the furnace off. Take the top cover off. Take the lower cover off. Take a picture of the wires where they go on the circuit board, with it clear which wires go to the outside, and which ones go to the t-stat inside. Then put it all back together and turn the switch back on so it at least works for now.

Comment: I would expect the person that ran the wire to warrant the work.